# The specified value is out of range

Tags: vba, collections, powerpoint, presentation

I am trying to write some code that returns in the Immediate Window the slide number of every slide that contains at least one Text Box with a red font, but the following error keeps popping up. Do you have ideas on how I can solve the problem?

Below the error I get:

```
Run-time error'-2147024809(80070057)
The specified value is out of range.
```

The line that causes it is:

```vb
ElseIf shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
```

This is the full code of the Subroutine:

```vb
    Sub redfont()
    
        Dim sld As Slide
        Dim shp As Shape
        Dim x As Byte
        Dim z, i
    
        With ActivePresentation
            z = .Slides(.Slides.Count).SlideNumber
            MsgBox z, vbDefaultButton1, "Total Slides"
        End With
    
        Dim myCol As Collection
        Set myCol = New Collection
    
        For i = 2 To z
            Set sld = ActivePresentation.Slides(i)
            For Each shp In sld.Shapes
                If x = 1 Then
                x = 1
                ElseIf shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
                    myCol.Add CStr(i), CStr(i)
                    x = 1
                End If
            Next shp
            x = 0
        Next
    
        Dim j As Long
        For j = 1 To myCol.Count
            Debug.Print myCol.Item(j)
        Next j
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: You might want to tune your logic up a bit because you have `If x = 1 Then x = 1`  Really I’m not sure how x should ever end up being 1?

Comment: Initially x=0 and once it becomes 1, I do not need that slide number again. Hence the elseif condition runs only once. This code runs fine in one presentation and in the other it gives this error. (the file is not protected)

Comment: All this narrative and updates in comments and we still don't know which line of code throws the error beyond *'keeps popping up'*.

Comment: The follwing is the errror line>>>>                                                                                        

ElseIf shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then

Comment: So, it's treating the RGBA value as a signed integer - rather than 4 8-bit unsigned integers. I have no solution, just this insight. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Since not all `Shapes` have a `TextFrame`, you need to check first whether your shape has one or not before trying to access it.

Use the [`.HasTextFrame`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shape.hastextframe) property for that purpose.

The general pattern is:

```vb
If shp.HasTextFrame Then
   'Access shp.TextFrame inside here
   'For example:
   shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "New Text"
End If
```

In your specific case the correct code would look like this:

```vb
For i = 2 To z
    Set sld = ActivePresentation.Slides(i)
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        If shp.HasTextFrame Then
            If shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
                myCol.Add CStr(i), CStr(i)
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
```

BTW: you don't need the `x` variable, just exit the loop when the first condition is met.